# jQuery Show & Hide Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs that need to be hidden (class named .hideable), and some divs that need to be shown (class named .toggleable. I have it working so far, which is great, but I`m having difficulties with the following; The hidden divs (.hideable) need to come back after the toggleable divs are hidden again.

here is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var topContainer = $(".toggleable");
    var topButton = $(".orsp a");
    topButton.click(function() {
        topContainer.slideToggle('slow');
        $(".hideable").hide();
    });
});
```

all help is welcome!
thanks, 
J.

Comment: Can you show your html

Comment: Can you post a working example in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: why is there need for html?

Comment: @Jonathan79 to understand the problem as your code seems to be correct

Comment: thanks guys for helping out. I see how jsfiddle can help, but for this problem, it was only about the jquery. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(".hideable").toggle();
```

instead of `jQuery.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you wnat try like [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/6bchS/)

HTML

```
<div style='display:none' class='hideable' >Hidden Div</div>
<div class='toggleable'>Toggleable div</div>

<input class='topButton' type='button' value='toggle'>
```

JS

```
$('.topButton').click(function() {
    $('.toggleable').slideToggle('slow', function() { $(".hideable").slideToggle(); });
});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6bchS/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use toggle to hide the .hideable div you can hide it using CSS and whenever you toggle .toggleable div you can check with Jquery whether it is hidden and if it is you can change it back to be shown. However Jakub's answer is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest choose toggle or toggle class

**Fiddle**

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/gcsHg/>?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var topContainer = $(".toggleable");
var topButton = $(".orsp a");
topButton.toggle(function() {
    topContainer.slideToggle('slow');
    $(".hideable").hide();
},function () {
topContainer.slideToggle('slow');
    $(".toggleable").hide();
 });
});
```